# 403 forbidden error after installed laravel ec2 with apache

Tags: laravel, apache, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance with AWS linux 2. And I added apache server. Added laravel to this directory

```
/var/www/html/laraveltest/
```

Added this to **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
   
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName my_ip
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laraveltest/public
       <Directory /var/www/html/laraveltest>
              AllowOverride All
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
              Require all granted
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm getting this in browser

[image]

It's 403 forbidden error. Restarted the server and removed .htaccess still get this

Comment: Don't you have a folder called `sitesAvailable` outside `conf`? How are you accessing the site? With an IP or a name?